# Create new df coulmns in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, sample

I have a df with column 'x' which i want to sample data from and store it in a new dataframe df_pull. This process i want to repeat in a for loop e.g. 10 times. My problem is that: 'name 'df_pull' is not defined'. Sure, this is beacause i did not defiend df_pull, but how do i create an empty df. This is not possible right? I was succsesfull by creating a lot if lists, but I am sure this is not the best solution.

```
for i in np.arange(10):
    df_pull[[i]] = df['x'].sample(frac=1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comrehension with `concat` and also is important [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for avoid same columns values (because index alignmenet):

```
r = np.arange(10)
L = [df['x'].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) for i in r]
df_pull  = pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=r)
```

Your solution with empty DataFrame and also `DataFrame.reset_index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'y':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'x':[1,3,5,7,1,0],

})

df_pull = pd.DataFrame()
for i in np.arange(10):
    df_pull[i] = df['x'].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df_pull)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  7  1  1  1  5  3  5  3  1
1  7  1  5  5  0  1  1  1  7  7
2  5  0  0  7  1  3  5  3  1  5
3  3  3  3  0  3  0  7  1  1  3
4  0  1  7  1  5  7  1  7  5  1
5  1  5  1  3  7  1  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty DateFrame
just

```
pull_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

if you want the same columns as the first df

```
pull_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```